# Regular expression to extract the path from a full file location

Tags: java, regex

I would like to have a regular expression to extract the path from a full file location

For example, having a path

```
#/home/java/bin/myfile
```

The regular expression should extract `/home/java/bin/`

Comment: I would like to have a regular expression to extract the path(to match the path as mentioned). Thanks.

Comment: Bohemian already provided the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why regular expression?

```
String s = "#/home/java/bin/myfile";
String result = s.substring(1, s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: What if path is not absolute and does not contain any `/` character?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the directory from the path using this line:

```
String dir = path.replaceAll(".*?(/.*/).*", "$1");
```

Here's some test code:

```
String path = "#/home/java/bin/myfile";
String dir = path.replaceAll(".*?(/.*/).*", "$1");
System.out.println(dir);
```

Output:

```
/home/java/bin/
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should not use lazy regex operator if you don't have to... Faster alternative to your solution would be `replaceAll("^[^/]*|[^/]*$", "");`

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ I did think of that, but decided against it because it's a regex for the negative of the target, whereas my regex captures the target and is IMHO easier to read and useful elsewhere, for example for extracting multiple instances from a string containing several paths. While performance is important, the difference in performance between the two would be negligible. It's always good to think of performance, but readability is more important. All that said, it's good to show your solution as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple regex pattern would be `.*\/(?!.*\/)|`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This is java: no need to escape slashes. In fact, if used as-is, this wouldn't compile

Comment: Also it doesn't actually work

Comment: Not sure why this is not matching the path, Please find my code.

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\/(?!.*\\/)|");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("#/home/java/bin/myfile");
    //The regular expression should extract /home/java/bin/
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Group 0 " + matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println("Group 1 " + matcher.group(1));
    }

Comment: @Bohemian - This is a standard regex format, that includes common escaping. Java requires to double an escape characters, but that is something well known. As this question and related answers may be helpful for other users, regardless of programming language, I prefer to use standard regex format.

Comment: @user3053015 - See http://ideone.com/HpddlU

Comment: Yes but the slashes are *not* part of regex - it's a language artefact of several languages. The escaping is not required, so best left out, along with the leading/trailing slashes. People using a language which uses slashes will know to add them and escape slashes within the expression. Better to keep code as minimal as possible.